# How to prevent Block Editor from adding id to block markup in save function?

Tags: block-editor

I am extending a core WP block (`core/group`), so that it has some added `div's` enabling me to display the block as I desire on front end.

In addition to the display customization (which is not possible with style properties alone - hence the added markup), the point of my extending the block with this added markup is so that on front end I can do jQuery actions, based on an `id` I am adding to my `container div`, as well as create a dynamic navigation menu with anchor links to the blocks based on presence of my extended blocks.

First, let me say up front, everything is already working precisely how I want on front end, and in the block editor, everything seems to be working great, except for one validation issue, which doesn't seem to be a show stopper, but nonetheless, I want to get rid of the validation error.

I am noticing that Wordpress is automatically adding an `id` to the core/group outer div: `<div class="wp-block-group" id="an-exercise-111"></div>`. This is causing the validation error, and I can't figure out how to stop it from doing so.

In my code, I don't see anyplace where this id could be getting added.

Here is my code that generates the custom block markup:

```
const addContentTypeMarkup = ( element, blockType, attributes ) => {
    // Do nothing if it's another block than our defined ones.
    if ( ! enableBlockContentTypeAttribute.includes( blockType.name ) ) {
        return element;
    }
    if ( attributes.contenttitle) {
        var post_id = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId();
        var title_slug = attributes.contenttitle.trim().split(/\s+/).join('-');
        var anchorid = title_slug+'-'+attributes.contentid;
        var iconclassbase='contenticon ';
        var iconclass='';
        switch(attributes.contenttype) {
            case 'exercise':
                iconclass =  'fas fa-guitar';
                break;
            case 'concept':
                iconclass = 'fas fa-atom';
                break;
            default:
                iconclass = 'fas fa-atom';
        }
        iconclass = iconclassbase + iconclass;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id = {`${anchorid}`} className = {`contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-${attributes.contenttype} navanchor`} data-id = {`${attributes.blockId}`}>
                    <div className = "heading d-flex flex-row">
                        <i className={`${iconclass} fa-7x`}></i>
                        <div className = "col">
                            <div className = "row"><span className="content-name">{attributes.contentname}</span></div>
                            <div className = "row"><h3 className="topictype-title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ { __html: attributes.contenttitle } }></h3></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {element}
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    } else {
        return element;
    }
};

addFilter( 'blocks.getSaveElement', 'my-blockmods/add-content-type-markup', addContentTypeMarkup);
```

Here is the message I get in admin panel, if I view console in Developer Tools:

```
<div id="an-exercise-111" class="contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-exercise navanchor" data-id="be3d05d6-a048-41c9-8dcf-5fcf121dd4a8"><div class="heading d-flex flex-row"><i class="contenticon fas fa-guitar fa-7x"></i><div class="col"><div class="row"><span class="content-name">Exercise</span></div><div class="row"><h3 class="topictype-title">an exercise</h3></div></div></div><div class="wp-block-group" id="an-exercise-111"></div></div>

Content retrieved from post body:

<div id="an-exercise-111" class="contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-exercise navanchor" data-id="be3d05d6-a048-41c9-8dcf-5fcf121dd4a8"><div class="heading d-flex flex-row"><i class="contenticon fas fa-guitar fa-7x"></i><div class="col"><div class="row"><span class="content-name">Exercise</span></div><div class="row"><h3 class="topictype-title">an exercise</h3></div></div></div><div class="wp-block-group"></div></div>
```

I see the nature of the problem - Wordpress Block Editor, upon `save`, is creating this element:

```
div class="wp-block-group" id="an-exercise-111"></div>
```

This element, shown above in the markup function simply as `{element}` contains the content of the block. I don't need it to have an `id`. Maybe Wordpress requires its blocks to have an `id`?  **So it seems the block editor is automatically setting it with an `id` that is the same as the `id` I set manually in the block markup function**, where I have `<div id="an-exercise-111" class="contenttype-wrapper...`

Any ideas?

thanks!

**NOTE**
If I don't use the `id` attribute in my custom `div` then everything validates. For example, if I use `someid` then all is fine. But the whole point to me needing to use `id` is so that anchor links work the way I want. So this gets back to original question - why is WP even adding the `id` to the div `<div class="wp-block-group" id="an-exercise-111">`? In block editor, I don't add an id to the core/group block, and in my filter, I don't set that id. Really, this is a mystery. Even if I could do this differently (and I will probably switch to render_block and do server side render), I would still like to understand why WP is doing what it is doing...

Comment: what are you trying to do here that lead you to creating this filter that has this problem? You've asked how to fix your solution rather than how to solve your original problem, and I'm almost certain that you are seeing this because you've built it wrong, not because you just need to remove an extra bit and need to know how. What is it supposed to do if it was working ok? This looks like something that should have been a wrapper block not a filter

Comment: I am extending core/group block to create in backend, say, an `exercise`, block, which will have certain formatting.  I place them on a custom post. So you can imagine a custom post `guitar_lesson` and within that post you have exercises, etc. These exercises are not posts - they are just blocks. Upon save_post, I detect these blocks in post_content and update some post meta so that I keep track of these blocks for use in a nav menu. All works great on front end. Just this validation error - no idea how this id is being added.

Comment: So your filter is what's adding the navigation menu? I'm trying to figure out how what you described in your comment would lead to the code in your question and I do not see the link. Even if you succeed it will not give you a navigation menu like you hoped as the individual parts will be spread throughout the entire post. Even if it did, this is a very complicated way to achieve that goal. What you're describing is essentially a document outline or table of contents though, there are far easier ways to do that, and they look nothing like the code you've shared

Comment: Is this filter trying to modify the blocks to add section headings automatically based on a block attribute? If so why aren't those headings a part of the block itself? Or a wrapper block that contains them? That would be the recommended way, not a filter. If you have a "step" then you need to create a step block that contains the other blocks. It should show up that way in the outliner sidebar too, it would greatly simplify your frontend code, eliminate this filter entirely as well as the problem you're asking about.

Comment: The nav menu I build dynamically via jQuery.  It works because of the markup I add to the block: `<div id = {`${anchorid}`} className = {`contenttype-wrapper sometopictype-${attributes.contenttype} navanchor`} content-id = {`${attributes.contentid}`} data-id = {`${attributes.blockId}`}>
` I suppose I wasn't clear - the block editing is so that I have custom version of a core/group block, whose added markup allows me to do some jQuery actions on front end. Everything is working - I just can't figure out why WP adds to the block {element} the same id I add to my custom div.

Comment: " If so why aren't those headings a part of the block itself?" That is exactly what I am doing - I am adding a div that contains an id, so that I can jQuery select it on front end, and link to it via anchor link.

Comment: it would be better to use a custom block, the save filter isn't meant to be used like this, it is unsurprising

Comment: I was trying to convey that the block should do it, not the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, rather the approach taken is incorrect, and this particular situation is not fixable.

The group blocks anchor attribute for the ID is stored in the markup itself not the HTML comment, so by introducing an ID at the top level you are changing its value. Once this is done, the output of the save component of the group block changes and that is where your ID is coming from.

Fundamentally, what you're doing is not how it should be done, and this approach is the wrong approach.

Instead, you should use containing blocks and compose your structure. Much in the same way that you can group blocks together in a group block, and give it an ID, you would be better off creating a dedicated block with a title and icon selection that has an ID.

If a container block isn't suitable, a step heading block would also work just as well.

The bonus would be that you could build the navigation trivially in PHP by parsing the blocks, either through `parse_blocks` then looping through to find these "step" blocks, or by adding a filter to `the_content`, or even a template function if you wanted to do it that way. Likewise, any question about building outliners for block based content would also be super useful to you.

Likewise a filter similar to what you have right now in PHP could be implemented using the block rendering filters at runtime to achieve this.

Comment: The navigation isn't really part of this question - I will edit my post to make clear. The whole point to my added markup to a core/group block, is so that on front end the block gets displayed how I want (with my added div's), and so that it enables me to do some jQuery actions on front end.

Comment: I use parse_blocks to keep track of my custom blocks. The reason I chose core/group is because I needed a very generic block in which I can add all sorts of content, as well as add my container div, and some heading sort of stuff. Everything is actually working as intended - I am just trying to understand why WP is adding the id in the first place that is causing the validation error.

Comment: @Brian it's very relevant because the entire approach is incorrect, the filter on the save hook in javascript is not the solution to your problem. You should not fix it, you should replace it with an alternative implementation. Even doing this exact thing but via the block rendering filter in PHP would be a major improvement, allowing you to insert the HTML at runtime. Otherwise I am not surprised block validation and differences are becoming a problem, you should expect this to happen when making those kinds of changes.

Comment: Additionally, this approach won't work well with full site editing as there's no preview of the heading and icons. There's also no schema information to validate off of because the group block doesn't possess those attributes. A block with inner blocks would be another solution to avoid this problem that is also better as a replacement for the group block. This filter is not a good way to do this, you should move away from it and not use the save hook in this way in the future

Comment: @Brian see my updated answer, the filter itself is the cause of the issue, there is no way to fix it so long as you're adding an `id` because of how group blocks store their ID's

Comment: Ok, in that case, I will look into container blocks. The main thing is that I don't want to do too much customization of a block. I chose the group block because you can add so many different content types, and in my case I need that flexibility, so that when I add an `exercise` it can contain text, images, video, etc. Is render_block filter an issue with performance, or nothing noticeable?

Comment: same as any other filter, it's not the filter itself that makes it slow, it's what you do in the filter that makes it slow. Don't go making HTTP requests or expensive DB queries. As for containing blocks, they can have any block you want inside them, unless you explicitly prevent it

Comment: Just one other thing - when you say 'container' block, do you mean a custom block I create, or an existing core block? When I read up on container blocks, I see this - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/container-block/ - which points me back to the core/group block...

Comment: a custom block you create, a container is basically any block that contains another block, e.g. a group, column, etc, but in this case you will want your own block. Thankfully it appears most of the new blocks save and edit components have already been built in the process of creating this filter, and can be hoisted straight out of the filter and into the new implementation, your `{element}` would get replaced with the `Innerblocks` component